# Accessing GMail "View as HTML" content programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, api, gmail

I love the "View as HTML" option in GMail when viewing attachments. I would love to be able to use this feature programatically, i.e. check a GMail inbox, read emails, if there are attachments, get the html view and use that content.

I'm looking to do this in C#. Does anyone know if this is possible or if there's another solution to easily get content from a GMail account, regardless of what format it's in? I.E html, pdf, Word doc, etc.

The GMail Inbox Feed API isn't good enough and before I start trying to build an IMAP solution that pulls in PDF/Word doc converters, I thought it'd be good to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the latest "preview PDF online" has been opened through Googles own GMail API.

I haven't had an option to look at it yet, though - but I read that it has been released. So you can just use your Google Docs to open the files directly from a simple `href`.

Comment: There is no GMail API, sadly. There's an XML feed, but it's rudimentary. I've since played with accessing the GMail account by Pop3, but that doesn't get me any closer to seeing a HTML view of the attachments. I can download the attachments (and I'm currently trialling some pdf/word doc reader components), but I want to leverage Google's "View as HTML" feature we see in GMail.